# Using JavaScript/JQuery, can you sort a HTML table column (ascending/descending) based on the column’s <td> class names?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, xslt

I'm currently working on a web page to manage course data, which dynamically produces a HTML table via a combination of *XSLT (1.0)* and *JavaScript* ([on the client method](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp)). The HTML table is then populated with live data supplied from an XML file.

**The Table:**

The HTML table contains four main columns (*Course*/*Location(s)*/*Credits*/*Date(s)*) and each row’s data relates to a `<Courses>` element in the XML File.

[image: HTML Table Output]

When the **Date(s)** column's `<td>` tags are constructed via XSLT (1.0), the XSLT code also makes a look-up in the XML stucture and works out the course's first available `<UnitStartDate>`, for example *Mechanical and Electrical Engineering* would be *3 Feb 2016*, as you can see from the figure above.

This `<UnitStartDate>` is then interpreted into a YYYYMMDD format and assigned as a **class name** to the Date(s) `<td>` at run-time, so in our previous example, the class name would be *20160203*, translating to `<td class="date 20160203"><br/><p>3 Feb 2016</p><p>18 Feb 2016</p><p>24 Feb 2016</p><br/></td>` in our HTML markup.

If no `<UnitStartDate>` exists, as is the case with the '*Leisure and Tourism*' course (Date TBC), *99999999* is assigned as the class name.

**HTML:**

```
<table class="upcomingcourses" border="1" style="width: 701px">
<thead>
   <tr>
    <th width="45%">Course</th>
    <th width="15%">Location(s)</th>
    <th width="5%">Credits</th>
    <th width="35%"><a href="javascript:sortTable()">Date(s)</a></th>
   </tr>
</thead>
  <tbody>

 <tr>
    <td class="centerTD">
        <a href="/courses/business-studies.html">Business Studies</a>
    </td>
    <td class="locations">
        <br/>
        <p>B7</p>
        <p>G6</p>
        <br/>
    </td>
    <td class="centerTD">
        <p>30</p>
    </td>
    <td class="date 20160204">
        <p>4 Feb 2016</p>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="centerTD">
        <a href="/courses/management-studies.html">Management Studies</a>
    </td>
    <td class="locations">
        <br/>
        <p>D8</p>
        <p>F2</p>
        <br/>
    </td>
    <td class="centerTD">
        <p>15</p>
    </td>
    <td class="date 20160101">
        <br/>
        <p>e-Learning: Jan-Feb 2016</p>
        <p>8-12 Feb 2016</p>
        <p>Presentation: 9 Mar 2016</p>
        <br/>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="centerTD">
        <a href="/courses/leisure-tourism.html">Leisure and Tourism</a>
    </td>
    <td class="locations">
        <br/>
        <p>C5</p>
        <br/>
    </td>
    <td class="centerTD">
        <p>15</p>
        <p>20</p>
    </td>
    <td class="date 99999999">
        <p>TBC</p>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="centerTD">
        <a href="/courses/mechanical-electrical-eng.html">Mechanical and Electrical Engineering</a>
    </td>
    <td class="locations">
        <br/>
        <p>A3 Workshop</p>
        <br/>
    </td>
    <td class="centerTD">
        <p>15</p>
    </td>
    <td class="date 20160203">
        <br/>
        <p>3 Feb 2016</p>
        <p>18 Feb 2016</p>
        <p>24 Feb 2016</p>
        <br/>
    </td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**The Question:**

So, with all that background information out the way, what would I actually like to achieve? Well, I eventually want to be able to sort each of the four main table columns (ascending/descending) via JavaScript or JQuery (I'm open to both options).

The first three columns from left-to-right (*Course*/*Location(s)* and *Credits*) are straightforward enough, but for the fourth column, *Date(s)*, I really want to be able to **sort the column in order (largest number to lowest and vice-versa) based on my 'date' class name (YYYYMMDD)**. This sorting process would be triggered by clicking the link in the Date(s) `<th>` (`sortTable()` function).

As you can see from the *Mechanical and Electrical Engineering* cell, its not just straightforward dates that are always included (details on e-Learning etc.).

Could this `ClassName` sort approach be achieved using JavaScript?

With a sort of the earliest dates (Class Names) to the latest, I would expect to see the following:

[image]

**Earliest:** `<td class="date 20160101"><br/><p>e-Learning: Jan-Feb 2016</p><p>8-12 Feb 2016</p><p>Presentation: 9 Mar 2016</p><br/></td>`

`<td class="date 20160203"><br/><p>3 Feb 2016</p><p>18 Feb 2016</p><p>24 Feb 2016</p><br/></td>`

`<td class="date 20160204"><p>4 Feb 2016</p></td>`

**Latest:** `<td class="date 99999999"><p>TBC</p></td>`

---

Thanks in advance everybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOM exposes the `rows` of a HTML table section, like a `tbody`, if you stuff them into a Javascript array, then you can sort them as needed and just need to `appendChild` them after sorting to have them in the right order, as the DOM methods on existing children move them.

So you can use a Javascript function that takes the cell you click on and then orders the rows:

```js
function sortTable(headerCell) {
  var table = headerCell.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
  var colIndex = headerCell.cellIndex;
  var rows = [];
  var tbody = table.tBodies[0];
  if (tbody != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tbody.rows.length; i++) {
     rows.push(tbody.rows[i]);
    }
    if (headerCell.dataset.order == 'ascending') {
     headerCell.dataset.order = 'descending';
      rows.sort(function(row1, row2) { 
       return row2.cells[colIndex].classList[1] - row1.cells[colIndex].classList[1];
      });    
    }
    else {
      rows.sort(function(row1, row2) { 
       headerCell.dataset.order = 'ascending';
       return row1.cells[colIndex].classList[1] - row2.cells[colIndex].classList[1];
      });
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
     tbody.appendChild(rows[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.sortable { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<table class="upcomingcourses" border="1" style="width: 701px">
<thead>
   <tr>
    <th width="45%">Course</th>
    <th width="15%">Location(s)</th>
    <th width="5%">Credits</th>
    <th width="35%" class="sortable" data-order="ascending" onclick="sortTable(this);">Date(s)</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
  <tbody>

 <tr>
    <td class="centerTD">
        <a href="/courses/business-studies.html">Business Studies</a>
    </td>
    <td class="locations">
        <br/>
        <p>B7</p>
        <p>G6</p>
        <br/>
    </td>
    <td class="centerTD">
        <p>30</p>
    </td>
    <td class="date 20160204">
        <p>4 Feb 2016</p>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="centerTD">
        <a href="/courses/management-studies.html">Management Studies</a>
    </td>
    <td class="locations">
        <br/>
        <p>D8</p>
        <p>F2</p>
        <br/>
    </td>
    <td class="centerTD">
        <p>15</p>
    </td>
    <td class="date 20160101">
        <br/>
        <p>e-Learning: Jan-Feb 2016</p>
        <p>8-12 Feb 2016</p>
        <p>Presentation: 9 Mar 2016</p>
        <br/>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="centerTD">
        <a href="/courses/leisure-tourism.html">Leisure and Tourism</a>
    </td>
    <td class="locations">
        <br/>
        <p>C5</p>
        <br/>
    </td>
    <td class="centerTD">
        <p>15</p>
        <p>20</p>
    </td>
    <td class="date 99999999">
        <p>TBC</p>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="centerTD">
        <a href="/courses/mechanical-electrical-eng.html">Mechanical and Electrical Engineering</a>
    </td>
    <td class="locations">
        <br/>
        <p>A3 Workshop</p>
        <br/>
    </td>
    <td class="centerTD">
        <p>15</p>
    </td>
    <td class="date 20160203">
        <br/>
        <p>3 Feb 2016</p>
        <p>18 Feb 2016</p>
        <p>24 Feb 2016</p>
        <br/>
    </td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order your records in javascript with [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) then remove unsorted records from table and add sorted with [jQuery.append](https://api.jquery.com/append/).

Or you can use [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) function to change order of records.